# Unfilled area in ggplot geom_area

Tags: r, ggplot2, fill

I'm trying to do a plot with `ggplot2` and `geom_area`. The fill is set by a variable. For some reason, only the 'outer' groups are filled. I can't figure out how to get the inner regions filled as well.

The same problem seems to occur [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28730083/filling-in-the-area-under-a-line-graph-in-ggplot2-geom-area) but no answer is given on how to solve it.

Below is an minimal example of the code i'm using and the resulting plot:

[image: and the resulting plot]

I'm using R 3.3 and ggplot2_2.1.0

Any help would be appreciated.

```
df <- data.frame(month = seq(from = as.Date("2016-01-01"), to = as.Date("2016-12-31"), by = "month"), 
             type = c(rep("past", times = 5), "current", rep("future", times = 6)), 
             amount = c(seq(from = 100, to = 1200, by = 100)))

df$type <- factor(df$type, levels = c("past", "current", "future"))


ggplot(data = df, aes(x = month, y = amount, fill = type)) + 
  geom_area()
```

Comment: The reason is that `current` occurs only once. So you do not have an area.

Comment: It is probably better to use `geom_bar(stat = 'identity')`

Comment: `ggplot(data = df, aes(x = month, y = amount, fill = type)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") `

Comment: Of course it makes complete sense that an area could not be drawn with one data point. Doh! I'm going to stick with the geom_area because the real plot is supposed to show the gradual increase of the variable. I'm going to mark the 'current' period with a vertical line. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added 2 points in time arround the "current" value in order to produce an area. The problem is that with only one point no area can be drawn.

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(month = seq(from = as.Date("2016-01-01"), to = as.Date("2016-12-31"), by = "month"), 
                 type = c(rep("past", times = 5), "current", rep("future", times = 6)), 
                 amount = c(seq(from = 100, to = 1200, by = 100)))

df <- rbind(df[1:5, ], 
            data.frame(month = as.Date(c("2016-05-15", "2016-06-15")),
                       type  = c("current", "current"),
                       amount = c(550, 650)),
            df[7:12, ])

df$type <- factor(df$type, levels = c("past", "current", "future"))


ggplot(data = df, aes(x = month, y = amount, fill = type)) + 
geom_area()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer Alex. This does indeed solve the fill issue. But after reading your answer and the comments above i've decided to go another route (see comment above).