# Area plot using R tidyverse, ggplot, geom_area

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, geom-area

I am using the follow code to generate an area plot using `tidyverse`, `ggplot` function and `geom_area`.

```
 library(tidyverse)
 set.seed(12345)
 df1 <- data.frame(a = c(2000:2020), b = rnorm(21,25,4), c = rep("x", 21))
 df2 <- data.frame(a = c(2006:2020), b = rnorm(15,40,7), c = rep("y", 15))
 df3 <- data.frame(a = c(2017:2020), b = rnorm(4,20,3), c = rep("z", 4))
 df <- rbind(df1, df2, df3)
 ggplot(df, aes(x=a, y=b, fill=c)) + geom_area() + theme(legend.position = "none")
```

This works, but there are two open triangles at the bottom, which I would like to have filled with green and blue, respectively. I thought I could solve this by changing the code like this:

```
 df1 <- data.frame(a = c(2000:2020), b = rnorm(21,25,4), c = rep("x", 21))
 df1 <- rbind(c("1999", "0","x"), df1)
 df2 <- data.frame(a = c(2006:2020), b = rnorm(15,40,7), c = rep("y", 15))
 df2 <- rbind(c("2005", "0","y"), df2)
 df3 <- data.frame(a = c(2017:2020), b = rnorm(4,20,3), c = rep("z", 4))
 df3 <- rbind(c("2016", "0","z"), df3)
 df <- rbind(df1, df2, df3)
 ggplot(df, aes(x=a, y=b, fill=c)) + geom_area(position=stack) + theme(legend.position = "none")
```

But now the plotting does not work at all anymore. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37992906/unfilled-area-in-ggplot-geom-area) did not help me. Could anybody help, please?

Comment: `rbind`ing different classes (`"1999"` onto a numeric column, for instance) is wrong. Create a *real* `data.frame` with the real types, and things might work better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)
df2 <- group_by(df, c) %>%
  summarize(a = min(a) - 1) %>%
  mutate(b = 0) %>%
  bind_rows(df) %>%
  arrange(a,c)
ggplot(df2, aes(x=a, y=b, fill=c)) +
  geom_area() +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image: ggplot2 area chart with holes filled in]

If the ramp-up for the first group is a problem, then we can take it out simply:

```r
df2 <- group_by(df, c) %>%
  summarize(a = min(a) - 1) %>%
  mutate(b = 0) %>%
  bind_rows(df) %>%
  arrange(a,c) %>%
  slice(-1)
ggplot(df2, aes(x=a, y=b, fill=c)) +
  geom_area() +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image: same plot with the first group not ramped]