# Fill area under and between certain lines using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here's the example data:

```
ex_data <- structure(list(variable = c("Act", "Act", "Act", "Act", "Act", 
"Act", "Act", "Act", "Act", "Act", "Act", "Act", "Act", "Act", 
"Act", "Act", "Act", "Act", "Act", "Act", "Act", "Act", "Act", 
"Act", "Act", "Act", "Act", "Act", "Act", "Act", "Act", "Act", 
"Act", "Act", "Act", "Act", "Act", "Act", "Proj", "Proj", "Proj", 
"Proj", "Proj", "Proj", "Proj", "Proj", "Proj", "Proj", "Proj", 
"Proj", "Proj", "Proj", "Proj", "Proj", "Proj", "Goal", "Goal", 
"Goal", "Goal", "Goal", "Goal", "Goal", "Goal", "Goal", "Goal", 
"Goal", "Goal", "Thresh", "Thresh", "Thresh", "Thresh", "Thresh", 
"Thresh", "Thresh", "Thresh", "Thresh", "Thresh", "Thresh", "Thresh"
), value = c(6.89658227475411, 6.89108850833475, 6.91060575775871, 
7.00129392659955, 7.1096850611615, 7.07369364373404, 7.06060119204421, 
7.21032922407943, 7.34249288006833, 7.39138104921065, 7.4318910161, 
7.5961207493889, 7.85673978348162, 7.92089086256755, 7.95756924344796, 
7.98326636757226, 8.0193147690931, 7.97898702366837, 8.08257378865854, 
8.07398725017176, 7.97609133959215, 8.09248918915805, 8.13257527841791, 
8.03078376104876, 7.88034051912236, 7.82481943232295, 7.72428815030338, 
7.55539008452296, 7.42128217313615, 7.45838229538017, 7.41767125677876, 
7.31265597647537, 7.35972091839823, 7.27265834882302, 7.15542963221048, 
7.1447264083441, 7.35752135743515, 7.59728236343906, 7.32707490147607, 
7.25109817340699, 7.20263208921773, 7.23082681383693, 7.24648885635746, 
7.3729353600057, 7.43036853995031, 7.53395376136055, 7.60535703635852, 
7.61387042389277, 7.60922305418595, 7.65197881774436, 7.63187616748886, 
7.65717987566166, 7.74016035808493, 7.79327615657051, 7.61036111666667, 
6.93055923840536, 6.98454642755329, 7.08191653567892, 7.149035614177, 
7.15703819845921, 7.15266967093479, 7.19286008867969, 7.17396359743953, 
7.19774908312196, 7.27575073659984, 7.32567958717628, 7.15373944966667, 
7.22547665280559, 7.2817611691513, 7.38327468613334, 7.45324989563134, 
7.46159301541492, 7.45703859310223, 7.49893924138947, 7.47923864413908, 
7.50403627814842, 7.58535715092323, 7.6374106334391, 7.45815389433333
), measure = c(5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5
), NewDate = structure(c(1354320000, 1356998400, 1359676800, 
1362096000, 1364774400, 1367366400, 1370044800, 1372636800, 1375315200, 
1377993600, 1380585600, 1383264000, 1385856000, 1388534400, 1391212800, 
1393632000, 1396310400, 1398902400, 1401580800, 1404172800, 1406851200, 
1409529600, 1412121600, 1414800000, 1417392000, 1420070400, 1422748800, 
1425168000, 1427846400, 1430438400, 1433116800, 1435708800, 1438387200, 
1441065600, 1443657600, 1446336000, 1448928000, 1451606400, 1438387200, 
1441065600, 1443657600, 1446336000, 1448928000, 1451606400, 1454284800, 
1456790400, 1459468800, 1462060800, 1464739200, 1467331200, 1470009600, 
1472688000, 1475280000, 1477958400, 1480550400, 1451606400, 1454284800, 
1456790400, 1459468800, 1462060800, 1464739200, 1467331200, 1470009600, 
1472688000, 1475280000, 1477958400, 1480550400, 1451606400, 1454284800, 
1456790400, 1459468800, 1462060800, 1464739200, 1467331200, 1470009600, 
1472688000, 1475280000, 1477958400, 1480550400), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), .Names = c("variable", "value", "measure", 
"NewDate"), row.names = c(5052L, 5053L, 5054L, 5055L, 5056L, 
5057L, 5058L, 5059L, 5060L, 5061L, 5062L, 5063L, 5064L, 5065L, 
5066L, 5067L, 5068L, 5069L, 5070L, 5071L, 5072L, 5073L, 5074L, 
5075L, 5076L, 5077L, 5078L, 5079L, 5080L, 5081L, 5082L, 5083L, 
5084L, 5085L, 5086L, 5087L, 5088L, 5089L, 5336L, 5337L, 5338L, 
5339L, 5340L, 5341L, 5342L, 5343L, 5344L, 5345L, 5346L, 5347L, 
5348L, 5349L, 5350L, 5351L, 5352L, 5593L, 5594L, 5595L, 5596L, 
5597L, 5598L, 5599L, 5600L, 5601L, 5602L, 5603L, 5604L, 5845L, 
5846L, 5847L, 5848L, 5849L, 5850L, 5851L, 5852L, 5853L, 5854L, 
5855L, 5856L), class = "data.frame")
```

I can create a geom_line() chart as seen here using:

`ggplot(ex_data, aes(x=NewDate, y=value, colour=variable)) + geom_line()`

[image: basic geom_line() chart]

However, I'd like to be able to fill in the area under the Proj (blue) line until it meets the Thresh (purple) line, the area under the Thresh line until it meets the Goal (green) line and everything under the Goal line to y = 0.

When I try a basic area chart for all lines, the chart seems to distort the y-values:

`ggplot(ex_data, aes(x=NewDate, y=value)) + geom_area(aes(fill=variable)) + geom_line()`

[image: basic area chart]

I tried to follow this example here: [Filling in the area under a line graph in ggplot2: geom_area()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28730083/filling-in-the-area-under-a-line-graph-in-ggplot2-geom-area)

The end result would be very similar to a forecast chart where the first line has no fill but the last 3 lines have fills between them like this one:
[image]

Comment: The series don't line up: how do you envision "fill[ing] in the area under the Proj (blue) line until it meets the Thresh (purple) line" for x < 2016? You might want to clarify what you are trying to express with the final plot

Comment: You're right, I believe I'd want to fill only where the dates overlap for those last 3 groups.

Comment: Best bet might be to use geom_polygon to trace the contours of what you want to fill. That will mean adding points for the 'lower' boundary of the fill zone to each series. Doesn't sound like this really adds any information to the plot though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `geom_area` stacks different fills, leading to the high y-values. You can turn this off with the position `argument`. This is probably closer to what you are after.

```
ggplot(ex_data, aes(x = NewDate, y = value, ymax = value, colour = variable, fill = variable)) + 
  geom_area(position = "identity") + 
  geom_line()
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a lot closer, now I just need to figure out how to fill area only under certain lines and limit the y-ranges for each group.