# Using ggplot2::geom_area() for filling area under geom_line() results with a "hole" at the border between 2 areas

Tags: r, ggplot2

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28730326/6105259), I tried to fill/color the area under the line using `geom_area()`. For some reason, I get a "hole" in my fill under the curve, and I don't understand why:

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(ggplot2)

my_df <- structure(list(pct = 1:90, value = c(1169, 1221, 1276, 1324, 
                                     1375, 1429, 1487.76, 1557, 1638, 1722, 1815, 1910, 1996, 2099, 
                                     2183, 2258, 2335, 2415, 2492, 2578, 2665, 2767, 2886, 3046, 3266, 
                                     3601.85, 4177, 5665.56, 69903.38, 90771.45, 106208.8, 120299.04, 
                                     135166.06, 150344.65, 167729.92, 188525.15, 213467.44, 245582.4, 
                                     291334.84, 364050.75, 513903.5, 1128914.58, 7816368.00000001, 
                                     41104774.86, 47947469.24, 54209175.2, 59851221.76, 65688467.7, 
                                     71559563.96, 77981826.05, 86998181.8, 106239490.88, 122193369.58, 
                                     151889642.13, 176958452.24, 206981422.15, 247329791.92, 266069046.55, 
                                     291213938.16, 330950339.58, 348310803.2, 365222833.82, 400510785.48, 
                                     425404324.16, 438221019.24, 457370633.75, 494181336.4, 514636464.46, 
                                     528620039.58, 553030448.06, 592935005.4, 607385156.58, 627329445.94, 
                                     675674400.259999, 699811981.52, 755630100.25, 801576337.94, 875804545.479999, 
                                     964945467.160001, 1070663697.17, 1203097325.6, 1296094399, 1477237728.04, 
                                     1652506972.57, 1818977179.62, 2170959782.6, 2881501337.19999, 
                                     4319009925.36, 6457753872.32, 11012727859.78)), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                               "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -90L))
my_df |> 
  mutate(my_fill = case_when(pct <= 44 ~ "A",
                             pct > 44 & pct <= 85 ~ "B",
                             pct > 85 ~ "C")) |> 
  ggplot(aes(x = pct , y = value)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_area(aes(fill = my_fill)) +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = c(1, 44, 86),
                   limits = c(1, 44, 86))
#> Warning: Continuous limits supplied to discrete scale.
#> ℹ Did you mean `limits = factor(...)` or `scale_*_continuous()`?
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-12-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Why is there no *fill* where `pct == 85`? There's data at that point:

```r
my_df |> filter(pct == 85)

## # A tibble: 1 × 3
##     pct       value my_fill
##   <int>       <dbl> <chr>  
## 1    85 1818977180. B
```

Comment: perhaps because you don't have any data points between 84 and 86? (I haven't checked ...)

Comment: thanks @BenBolker – there is. I updated the post to reflect that.

Comment: can you show us the data for (say) `83 <= pct & pct <= 87` ? I still think this is some kind of boundary problem ...

Comment: `limits=c(1,42,86)` makes no sense to me, nor does `scale_x_discrete`. Do you instead mean `scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1, 44, 86), limits = c(1, 90))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A already guessed by @BenBolker the issue is some kind of "boundary" problem or put differently, by mapping on `fill` your area chart is split into three parts, which however leaves some gaps at the boundaries, i.e. the first area ends at 44, but the second starts at 45, leaving a gap between 44 and 45 and the same for the second/third area.

One option to fix that would be to add some helper rows, e.g. below I add two helper rows at 44.5 (A/B) and two at 85.5 (B/C). Doing so e.g. area A now ends at 44.5, likewise area B starts at 44.5, thus leaving no gap. Also note that in this case we have to set `position="identity"` and I also switched to `stat="identity"`.

Finally, note that I switched to `scale_x_continuous`.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

my_df |>
  mutate(my_fill = case_when(
    pct <= 44.5 ~ "A",
    pct > 44.5 & pct <= 85.5 ~ "B",
    pct > 85.5 ~ "C"
  )) |>
  add_row(
    pct = rep(c(44.5, 85.5), each = 2),
    my_fill = c("A", "B", "B", "C")
  ) |>
  mutate(
    value = ifelse(
      is.na(value),
      approx(pct, value, xout = pct)[["y"]], value
    )
  ) |>
  arrange(pct, my_fill) |> 
  ggplot(aes(x = pct, y = value)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_area(
    aes(fill = my_fill),
    position = "identity",
    stat = "identity"
  ) +
  scale_x_continuous(
    breaks = c(1, 44, 86)
  )
```

[image]